# ImagePicker library for React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with the image picker library in my react native project.
¨I am using expo so I added this to my app.json file:
"infoPlist": {
"NSCameraUsageDescription": "This app uses the camera to add pictures to posts.",
"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "This app needs access to your photo library to select and upload photos."
}, under the ios tag.

This is my dependencies:
"dependencies": {
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
"expo": "~48.0.18",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
"react-native-image-picker": "^5.4.0",
"react-native-switch": "^1.5.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
},

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {View, Button, Image} from "react-native"
import \* as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker'

const ImagePickerComponent =() =\> {
const\[selectedImage, setSelectedImage\] = useState(null);

    const openImagePicker = ()=> {
        ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({}, (response) => {
            if(response.didCancel) {
                console.log("User cancelled image picker");
            } else if(response.error) {
                console.log("Image picker error:", response.error);
            } else {
                setSelectedImage(response.uri);
            }
        });
    };
    
    return (
        <View>
            <Button title="Selected Image" onPress={openImagePicker}/>
            {selectedImage && <Image source={{uri: selectedImage}} style={{width: 200, height: 200}}/>}
        </View>
    );

};
export default ImagePickerComponent;

´´´

The error I am getting is: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'launchImageLibrary' of null
```